# How to insert full screen borders in the foundation 6 grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I should make an html page in foundation 6 and I'm having problems with full screen borders.

I tried to implement the following code using before and after in the css for the edges but I did not get a great result

```
<section class="grid-container-background margin-t0 firstSect">
    <div class="grid-container titleContainer">
        <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell small-12 medium-9 medium-offset-3 large-11 large-offset-1 section-title">
                <h2 class="right-border title blueTitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 medium-offset-3 large-10 large-offset-1">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
                    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="grid-container-background blue margin-t0 secondSect">
    <div class="grid-container titleContainer">
        <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="column small-12 medium-6 large-6">
                <div class="cell small-12 large-6 section-title">
                    <h3 class="left-border title whiteTitle text-center">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
                        <br />consectetur adipisci elit
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 medium-offset-3 large-9 large-offset-2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
                        ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column small-12 medium-6 large-6">
                <div class="cell small-12 large-6 section-title">
                    <h3 class="left-border title whiteTitle text-center">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
                        <br />consectetur adipisci elit
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 medium-offset-3 large-9">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
                        ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<style>
    .grid-container-background.blue {
    background-color: #00AEEF;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title.blueTitle {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #00AEEF;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title.whiteTitle {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title.right-border:before {
    right: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title.right-border:after {
    content: "";
    /* background: black; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    width: 9999px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #00AEEF;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title.left-border:before {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    }
    .grid-container.titleContainer .title.left-border:after {
    content: "";
    /* background: black; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    width: 9999px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

I often use bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to learn foundation 6 (with wordpress) so I'm confused ...
How could I do to get what is shown in the attached image?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ6TQ.jpg

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: This design in the image does not look like a good one.

Comment: What do you mean? t's a draft to understand the problem ... isn't it clear?

Comment: I can not publish the real draft ...however my problem is with borders that come out of the container of the main content, as seen in the loaded image

Comment: I meant that it is too complicated what the designer wants.

Comment: mmh ok... complicated or impossible?